# How to create a .pdb file with all info needed in lists/arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, file, pdb

I have the atom number(list), atom name(list), CA coordinates(array), residue number(list) and residue name(list) all output/calculated in several lists/arrays. How could I create a .pdb file with all those information in Python? I have installed the Biopython package. Thanks!

Comment: Right know I don't really have an idea with how to start, because in stack all the solutions are using Biopython.

Comment: Assuming you think about pdb = Protein Data Bank files, since it is a text file format you can easily write it in standard Python; but you need to fully understand the [specification](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/v3.3.html), which is quite complex. That is, if you don't want to use a library that already knows how to do the task for you :)

Comment: The output file is good to only include the info of all C-alphas in the ATOM portion.

Comment: I have installed the biopython package